# Wake On Lan server for a local network - looking for software

Tags: linux, open-source, wake-on-lan

I'm looking for a tool that let me register computers on a network (probably taking them from an LDAP database, that would be gorgeus), and then by using a web interface, wake them by sending a WOL magic packet.

Only FOSS software, please

This doesn't seem a very complicated software to do, so I can't believe I can't find anything out there. Maybe I'm not looking in the correct places?

Comment: I've mostly seen that feature in firewalls (pfSense, for example).  Have you checked your firewall?

Comment: I want the users to access the interface, so giving access to the firewall is not an option. I've taken a look at pfsense but I was looking for a more specific software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good Ubuntu wakeonlan package (I'm sure it will be available for other distros). I don't imagine it being too complicated to create a web frontend for this.
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wakeonlan

Also, most Draytek routers have this functionality built in. They maintain a database of IP/MAC pairs and allow you to send out WoL packets with a web GUI.

Comment: I think that I'll start by making a Shell script that gets the hosts from an LDAP database, and uses the wakeonlan utility as you suggest. From there, a web frontend should be easy to make.

Answer (score 1):

datagramm and charlesbridge are correct. I've had no problem using pfSense and Draytek modems as well.

It's worth noting WoL uses broadcast packets - if you are not local to the machines and trying to access via internet you will not have any joy and normally VPN's do not normally transmit broadcasts either.

It is possible to sent broadcasts over VPN but my preference was to use the main router on each site to wake up it's local computers.